# Different index has different time zone in kibana, how to set it?

Tags: kibana

Regarding Kibana, different index has different time zone. How could I customize time zone for different index?

I have two indexes in my ES cluster. The first one was indexed by python API, the second one was indexed by Logstash.

However, When I wanna show data in dashboard on kibana, I just found the time zone for the two index are different. For example, the time zone of time field in the two different original logs are same, let's say one of the time is 00:00:00. The one index that I import by python API shows the correct time, which is 00:00:00, another import by Logstash one shows the time is 08:00:00. My kibana advanced setting about time zone is browser. If I change the kibana advanced setting, it will change the whole time fields for two indexes.

What I wanna achieve is how to make the second index shows time field with the correct time zone?

Here is my Logstash config file filter part.

```
filter {
mutate {  
    split => ["message", "|"]
    add_field => {
        "start_time" => "%{[message][1]}"
        "end_time" => "%{[message][2]}"
        "channel" => "%{[message][5]}"
        "[range_time][gte]" => "%{[message][1]}"
        "[range_time][lte]" => "%{[message][2]}"
    }
} 
date {
     match => ["start_time","yyyyMMddHHmmss"]
}
ruby {   
    code => "event.set('temp', event.get('@timestamp').time.localtime)"   
}  
ruby {  
    code => "event.set('@timestamp',event.get('temp'))"  
}  
mutate {  
    remove_field => ["message", "temp"]  
}
```

The config can successfully changed @timestamp time, which same as start_time field. However, when I use Kibana to show the data, it still shows the date time zone 8 hours more. For example, in a record, time is 00:00:00, in kibana, it shows 08:00:00. How could I make start_time and end_time field shows correctly in kibana?

Comment: Can you provide some more details about your issue and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: OK, I updated my question. Any other information you need ?

Comment: Can you also show your Logstash configuration?

Comment: Val, I updated the question, tell me if you need more information.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve with the `date` + two `ruby` filters?

Comment: Just ignore the date{} part.

Comment: Could you add my Facebook?  ^-^

Comment: I don't get why you're using ruby filters for setting the date. Can you explain what's the idea behind this?

Comment: I'm gonna use another new kibana server to show the data. And just set kibana advanced setting to change the time zone. Thank you Val.